# Deciding whether the language of a CFG equals some specific regular language

Tags: undecidability

I was wandering if $L = \{\langle G \rangle \mid \ G \text{ is a context free grammar and } \mathcal L(G) = A \}$ is decidable where A is a some regular language. Is 
$L' = \{ \langle G \rangle \mid \ G \text{ is a context free grammar and } \mathcal L(G) = \overline A \}$ decidable ?  I feel like $L'$ should be decidable, but can't see how. Or does it depends on $A$?

Comment: Neat question!  Are you asking if L(G) = A for a particular A that you fixed.  Or, are you asking is L(G) is a regular language?

Comment: It seems that the question was clarified to be about a particular fixed A.  Thank you.  I think that the other question is interesting as well though.  ☺

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your choice of $A$. For example, the problem $\{\langle G \rangle \mid L(G) = \Sigma^* \}$ is undecidable, while $\{\langle G \rangle \mid L(G) = \phi \}$ is decidable.

Also, the two languages that you have given (the one with $A$ and the other with $\overline{A}$) are equivalent since regular languages are closed under complementation.

Comment: Is there an interesting characterization of the languages $A$ such that $L(G) = A$ is decidable?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware of any such characterization. But it's an interesting question and I suggest that you post it as another question.